# Trying to store some bytes sent from my iOS app into a variable in my Arduino sketch

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, serial-port, arduino

I’m currently writing an iOS app that passes strings to the Arduino via Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). I’m using RedBearLab’s BLE shield and my code for iOS and Arduino are based on their open source code from their GitHub https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS.

The problem I’m having is I don’t know how to store the NSData that I sent from my iOS app via BLE to a variable in my Arduino’s sketch.

Here is my iOS code:

```
#import “BLE.h”  // from RedBearLab’s Github

- (IBAction)sendText:(id)sender
{
    NSData *textInput = [self.textField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (ble.activePeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {

        [ble write:textInput]; // ble is a object that follows the CoreBluetooth protocol written by RedBearLab

        NSLog(@"Date sent..");
    }
}
```

Here you can find the `write:(NSData *)d` method from the [BLE.m](https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS/blob/master/BLEFramework/BLE/BLE.m)

My Arduino has no problem receiving my textInput. Now let say my `textInput` is “Hello”. Arduino’s serial monitor will show the following message when I run the Arduino’s sketch provided by RedBearLab [`SimpleChat.ino`](https://github.com/RedBearLab/BLEShield/blob/master/Arduino/libraries/RBL_BLEShield/examples/SimpleChat/SimpleChat.ino):

```
Evt Device Started: Standby
Advertising started
Evt Connected
Evt Pipe Status
Evt Pipe Status
Pipe Number: 2
Hello   // <--------my inputString
Evt link connection interval changed
```

So by looking at the serial monitor, my Arduino have no problem receiving my NSData from my iOS app. However, I have no idea how to store `Hello` into a variable (preferably a char[]) so I could put it into another function in my own Arduino sketch. If you look at the [`SimpleChat.ino`](https://github.com/RedBearLab/BLEShield/blob/master/Arduino/libraries/RBL_BLEShield/examples/SimpleChat/SimpleChat.ino), the program has a line which is `Serial.write(ble_read());`. I know I have to store the result of ble_read() into a variable, but I have no idea what `type` I should use to store the variable. According to the [`ble_shield.cpp`](https://github.com/RedBearLab/BLEShield/blob/master/Arduino/libraries/RBL_BLEShield/ble_shield.cpp), the `ble_read()` function returns a `int`, but what I really want is something like char[] so it can represent the `textInput`. Can someone familiar with C and Arduino help me out? Thanks.